# Unable to terraform init with a new artifactory remote backend

Tags: terraform, artifactory

I am trying to enable a new remote backend to terraform (v0.12.30) using artifactory. My configuration looks like this:

```
terraform {
backend "artifactory" {
    username = "correct-username"
    password = "correct-password"
    url      = "https://correct-url.com/artifactory"
    repo     = "correct-artifact-repo"
    subpath  = "correct-subpath"
  }
}
```

On running init, Terraform tries to copy over the local state files to the Artifactory backend. But always fails with a 500 error.

> Error: Error copying state from the previous "local" backend to the newly configured
> "artifactory" backend:
> Failed to upload state: Non-2xx code returned: 500. Message follows:
> <html>
> <head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
> <body bgcolor="white">
> <center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
> <hr><center>nginx</center>
> </body>
> </html>

I tested the Artifactory API by uploading something to the same folder and same sub-path using the same credentials as used in the Terraform backend, and it succeeded. Example of the CURL command used below:

```
$ curl -u correct-username:correct-password -X PUT "https://correct-url.com/artifactory/correct-artifact-repo/correct-subpath/terraform-2.test" -T /my/local/path/terraform-2.test
```

I am not sure why terraform is getting a 500 response from artifactory. Any ideas on how to debug this issue/on how to fix this?

Comment: Try looking at the Artifactory and look for the exception which is causing the 500 error

Answer (score 0):

I just had the exact same issue.
Can I assume you set the http_proxy and https_proxy setting? If so can you try using the no_proxy setting and add the URL of your Artifactory

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).